# How to control the vertical scroll bar of a v-card?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a v-card component that uses class="overflow-y-auto", so I get a vertical scrollbar.
The problem is that when I'm changing the page with v-pagination component, the v-card's content changes but the scrollbar stays at the bottom.
Is there a way to control its vertical position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select your element and then force scroll it up

```
// Get element
let obj = document.getElementByID("yourElementID");
// Set scroll position to 0 (top) 
obj.scrollTop = 0;
```

See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrolltop.asp for more infos

You can also select the element with VueJS `$refs` if you want : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs

Answer (score 0):

On your pagination click just write the following function code:

```
scrollToTop() {
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

Comment: Actually the window is always at (0, 0), but the scrollbar that I want to control is the one on the v-card